# Время генерации страницы Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть приложение на Ruby on Rails, которое отрабатаывается за 0,8 секунды

```
Completed 200 OK in 733ms (Views: 552.5ms | ActiveRecord: 57.9ms)
```

Мы оптимизировали запросы к базе, как видно, из базы всё что нужно вытаскивается 60ms. Но общее время генерации страницы -- дофига, 733ms, и база съедает лишь немного из этого.

В связи с чем вопросы:

1) "Views: 552.5ms" - это время, за которое были сгенерированы все использующиеся вьюхи? Или что-то иное?

2) Поможет ли уменьшению времени генерации страницы (в среднем по палате, я осознаю, что я не показываю код) настройка nginx (сейчас там настройки дефолтные) и переезд на SSD диск (вот про диск -- особенно интересно)? На сколько способен увеличить время генерации страницы переезд на SSD?)

Comment: Вопрос интересный, дайте лог?

Answer (score 2):

1. Да.
2. В среднем да.

Но вообще я бы начал с того, что посмотрел логи.
По дефолту туда пишется инфа вида:

> Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-09-03 13:16:04 +0300
>   Processing by Public::PagesController#index as HTML
>
> User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
>
> Rendered public/pages/index.ru.html.slim within layouts/public/main (189.9ms)
>
> Rendered layouts/public/_header.html.slim (4.8ms)
>
> Rendered layouts/public/_footer.html.slim (3.3ms)
>
> Completed 200 OK in 2788ms (Views: 2768.8ms | ActiveRecord: 2.9ms)

Здесь можно хотя бы примерно понять что и сколько рендерится.
Если нужна более точная информация то нужен профайлер. Лично мне нравится NewRelic.

Ну и на практике у меня была похожая ситуация когда из БД возвращалось много лишних данных, которые потом просто "не показывались".